How to calculate the double sine function via Sage or Pari/GP to high precision?
From a paper of Ruijsenaars, we can extract the following integral representation for the logarithm of the double sine function:
$$log(S_2(w,z)) = \int_0^\infty \left( \frac{e^{-y(1+w-z)}-e^{-yz}}{(1-e^{-y})(1-e^{-wy})} - \frac{1}{y}(\frac{2z}{w}-\frac {1}{w} -1 ) \right)  \frac{dy}{y} $$
In Sage, it is straightforward to implement this function using the procedure "numerical_integral". It works just fine and produces results in perfect alignment with the known values of the double sine function. (E.g., we have $S_2(w,1) = \sqrt{w}$).
My problem is, that I don't know how to increase the number of digits I can get using "numerical_integral". I only get around 16 digits in the decimal expansion, but for my applications I need at least 32.
Question 1: How to increase the number of digits in Sage for the output of the procedure "numerical_integral"?
In other words, how can I increase the precision of the procedure "numerical_integral"?
Here is my code:
numerical_integral(( (e^(-(1+w-z)*y)-e^(-z*y))/((1-e^(-y))*(1-e^(-w*y))) -1/y*(2*z/w-1/w-1) )/y,0,+Infinity,max_points=200)

I tried to use Gp/Pari, which automatically gives a larger number of digits, using the procedure "intnum". If I do the straightforward implementation of the same code which runs nicely on Sage, I don't get any output. (The procedure uses enormous amount of memory, but doesn't produce any output.
Question 2: How do I compute the double sine function in Gp/Pari?
Here is the gp Code (used in Sage):
gp("s2(y,w,z) = ( (exp(-(1+w-z)*y)-exp(-z*y))/((1-exp(-y))*(1-exp(-w*y))) -1/y*(2*z/w-1/w-1) )/y  ")

gp("intnum(y = [0,2],+oo, s2(y,w,z))")


I don't know a complete solution for this, but Sage lets us create a "real field" of specified numeric precision.  I need to do some experiments to see how this propagates into the numerical_integral function.
